# Assignment of arrays in Intel Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-fortran

I had an old Fortran 90 code with the following command:

```
data1(1:100) = data_all(:)
```

where `data_all` is a bigger array then `data1`.
Since I know that this is not a robust syntax, it worked good when using Visual Studio 2008.

I recently switched to Visual Studio 2013, and I am not able to use this code anymore, since it tries to fill the 101th position of `data1`.
What are the correct Compiler options to accept that?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't include a FORTRAN compiler. Which compiler/addon are you using? Which language version does it target? It's almost certain that FORTRAN90 is *not* the default version.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013, with Intel Parallel Studio XE 2017

Comment: VS is just the IDE. I'll bet that Intel Parallel Studio targets Fortran 2008 by default

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. What's your suggestion?

Comment: *"I recently switched to Visual Studio 2013, and I am not able to use this code anymore, since it tries to fill the 101th position of "data1"* You have to explain more. What makes you think it does that? I am quite sure the problem is somewhere else in the code you are not showing. Please supply a [mcve]

Comment: If the shape of the arrays does not conform, then the code is not legal Fortran 90. But it is not clear what you are trying to do and why. Why would you assign a larger array to a smaller array? **If you have an error message, please show it!** We need to see more. The code end the error you are getting.

Comment: No matter which compiler you use, you will need to fix the source code.

Comment: I agree with you all, I should fix the source code. Maybe I had some settings that hide the problem, but it's time to correct it. Thank you and sorry

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
data1(1:100) = data_all(1:100)
```

If data1 is 100 elements then

```
data1 = data_all(1:100)
```

If you want others then:

```
data1 = data_all(istart:(istart + (SIZE(data1) - 1))
```